# Fetch/Then chain behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a chain of then statements to transform data after a fetch request.  The code is within a React app, but I think this is just a Javascript question.

Here's my current code:

```
componentDidMount(){

    fetch(this.state.dataRouteDirections)
        .then(data => data=data.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .then(data => data.unshift(this.state.emptyDirections))
        .then(data => this.setState({directions:data})) 
        .then(()=>{
          var makes = this.state.directions.map(directions=>directions.acf.make); //get all make categories

          function removeDuplicates(arr){
            let unique_array = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
                return index===self.indexOf(elem);
              });
            return unique_array
          }

          makes = removeDuplicates(makes);
          this.setState({makes:makes});
        })    
}
```

The line giving me trouble is ".then(data => data.unshift(this.state.emptyDirections))".  It is telling me that the variable data is undefined in this statement.  Indeed, if I replace this line with the same line as above, console logging data twice, the first console log logs correctly and the second is undefined.

What am I not understanding about fetch/then/JS?  I'm coming from a PHP background and async stuff is still a challenge.

Question is answered below, here's my updated code:

componentDidMount(){

```
    fetch(this.state.dataRouteDirections)
        .then(data => data=data.json())
        .then(data => {data.unshift(this.state.emptyDirections); return data;})
        .then(data => this.setState({directions:data})) 
        .then(()=>{
          var makes = this.state.directions.map(directions=>directions.acf.make); //get all make categories

          function removeDuplicates(arr){
            let unique_array = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
                return index===self.indexOf(elem);
              });
            return unique_array
          }

          makes = removeDuplicates(makes);
          this.setState({makes:makes});
        })    
}
```

Comment: `console.log()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: You need to return something from your `then()` to pass it along to the next `.then()`. Since arrow functions have an implicit return, and `console.log()` returns undefined, your third `.then()` receives `undefined` as `data`

Answer (score 6):

The reason you are having this is because `console.log(data)` returns `undefined`. You should write smth like:

```
.then(data => {console.log(data); return data})
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm starting to see how the data variable needs to be explicitly returned so that the chain is not broken.

Comment: @PeterBreen In all reality, this doesn't need to be chained like this - you can put all of the code into a single `.then()` callback function.

Comment: That make sense also, @mhodges

Comment: A reusable function might help here:  `const tap = fn => data => {fn(data); return data;}`  Then you could do `.then(tap(console.log))` or even `const log = tap(console.log)` ... `.then(log)`